# Using Two Sets of Words for a Find and Replace RE

Tags: python

How would I use a set of words that I want replaced with another set of words inside a regular expression?

I gave it my best shot and here is what I ended up with (of course it doesn't do what I want):

```
count = 0
count2 = 0
set1 = ['word1','word2','word3']
set2 = ['new_word1','new_word2','new_word3']
with open(file, 'r+') as book:
    for line in book:
        if count<2:
            set1var = set1[count]
            set2var = set2[count2]
            reg1 = re.sub(r''+set1var,r''+set2var,line)
                    f.write(reg1)
                    if line != reg1:
                            count+=1
                            count2+=1
```

Comment: Probably not a good use of regexes. You'll be better off splitting your input line on spaces, then iterating over each word and seeing if it is your dictionary or not. Then reassembling the line.

Comment: Another idea: have a dictionary of old_word -> new_word. Construct a regexp that is the set of said dict's keys, joined by '|'. That's your search regexp. As a substitute value, look-up in dict using the found string.

Comment: Could either of you show an example the dictionary method?

Comment: @NitzanShaked, that's exactly how I would do it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is a good example:

```
>>> import re
>>> set1 = ['word1','word2','word3']
>>> set2 = ['new_word1','new_word2','new_word3']
>>> translation = dict(zip(set1, set2))
>>> 
>>> 
>>> text = '''
... here I am word1 talking about word2.
... ipsum ipsumipsum ipsum ipsum ipsum ipsum ipsum
... ipsum ipsumipsum word1 ipsum ipsum ipsum ipsum
... ipsum ipsumipsum ipsum ipsum word2 ipsum ipsum
... ipsum ipsumipsum ipsum ipsum ipsum ipsum ipsum
... '''
>>> 
>>> # compile a pattern matching any of the words
... pattern = re.compile('(%s)' % '|'.join(set1))
>>> 
>>> def translate(match):
...     return translation[match.group(0)]
... 
>>> # replace with: for line in book:
>>> for line in text.splitlines():
...     print pattern.sub(translate, line)
... 

here I am new_word1 talking about new_word2.
ipsum ipsumipsum ipsum ipsum ipsum ipsum ipsum
ipsum ipsumipsum new_word1 ipsum ipsum ipsum ipsum
ipsum ipsumipsum ipsum ipsum new_word2 ipsum ipsum
ipsum ipsumipsum ipsum ipsum ipsum ipsum ipsum
>>>
```

I am not using `count` or `count2` though, I assumed you want to replace all occurences.
Since I am using text in my example and not a file here is what you need:

```
with open(outputfile, 'w') as output:
    with open(file, 'r+') as book:
        for line in book:
            output.write(pattern.sub(translate, line))
```

Comment: Would I just take the file and assign a variable called text?

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean to get this done:

```
inputdata=open(file).read()
for initial,final in zip(set1,set2):
    inputdata=inputdata.replace(initial,final)
print str #or write to file
```

Comment: Great solution... but don't use reserved names 'str' and 'new'.

Comment: @tdelaney Correctly said. How could I do such a stupidity ? Edited the answer. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: `new` is not special in Python (even if the syntax highlighter thinks so). `str` is the name of a built-in type, so it's better to avoid using it as a variable name (but it would work).